# By Using python pil, I want to make image centered with text from url and download. How to do it?

Tags: python, django

I input a text at url, and want to get downloaded image that the text is centered.

for example,
when I input,
http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/hello, then an image is downloaded.
That image centers the text 'hello'

```
def homework(request, name):
text = name
img = Image.new('RGB',(256,256),(0,0,0))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

font = ImageFont.load_default().font
draw.text((128,128), text, font = font, fill="black")

with open(img, 'rb') as f:
    response = HttpResponse(f, content_type='image/jpeg')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="textimage"'
    return response
```

By using python pil.

How to do it?

Comment: yes,
def homework(request, name):
    text = name
    img = Image.new('RGB',(256,256),(0,0,0))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

    font = ImageFont.load_default().font
    draw.text((128,128), text, font = font, fill="black")

    with open(img, 'rb') as f:
        response = HttpResponse(f, content_type='image/jpeg')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="textimage"'
        return response
I continuously get error..

Comment: Please edit your question containing it, it's almost impossible to read from the comments

Comment: Now I edited. Please help..

Answer (score 0):

```
#install PIL (Pillow) via Pip

from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import ImageDraw 

#position of Text
x = 50
y = 50

#font color as tuple
color = (255, 255, 255)

#download the image to the local system and open it
img = Image.open("1.jpg")

#draw image and prepare font
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
font = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', size=30)

#draw text on image
draw.text((x, y),"Sample Text", color,font=font)

#save the new image, that contains the text
img.save('sample-out.jpg')
```

Comment: umm.. I want to draw text inputted, not "Sample Text"

Then, How can I do?

I input text(inputted) instead of "Sample Text", I continuously get UnicodeEncodeError..

Comment: "sample text" can be replaced by a Variable. Make sure to pass a string. Is "text(inputted)" a function you worte? does it return a string?

Comment: In my code above, I wrote 'def homework (request, name):'. Is name not variable? when I replace "sample text" by name, i get UnicodeEncodeError. I use it at django.